# C programming - how to stop counting if load function is break out?

Tags: c

I have a question that is needed to ask. Hope someone can help me out.

I am writing a function that prompts users for names, hours worked, and hourly rate using parameter passing, and pass by reference. If the user input "-1" in any field, break out of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct userdata
{
char name[20];
float hours;
float rate;
float gross;
float base;
float overtime;
float taxes;
float net;
}data;

int LoadEmployeeFromKey(data *d)
{
    char name[20];
    float rate, hours;
    printf("Enter an employee name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", name, 20);
    if (strcmp(name, "-1") == 0)
         return;
    printf("Worked Hours: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &hours);
    if (hours == -1.0f)
         return 1;
    printf("Hourly rate: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &rate);
    if (rate == -1.0f)
         return 1;

    strcpy_s(d->name, 20, name);
    d->hours = hours;
    d->rate = rate;
    return 1;
}
```

There is nothing wrong in here, this function works well. But the real problem when I work in main().

```
void main()
{
data employee[10];
int count = 0;
int option;
int stop = 0;
int i = 0;
FILE EmployeeFromFile[20];
FILE *File;
while (!stop)
{
    puts("---Main Menu---\n");
    puts("CHOOSE A FOLLOWING OPTION:");
    puts("1. Add an employee info from keyboard.");
    puts("2. Add employees info from a text file.");
    puts("3. Print all employees info.");
    puts("4. Edit an employee info.");
    puts("5. Print an employee and salary.");
    puts("6. Print all employees and salary.");
    puts("7. Save and Quit the program.\n");

    scanf_s("%d", &option);
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        LoadEmployeeFromKey(&employee[count]);
        Calculation(&employee[count]);
        count++;
        break;
```

Please ignore other things, when I debug, if I input "-1" in any field of (name, hours, or rate), it breaks and goes back to "Main Menu"; however, "count" is still counting (it still plus 1) leading to error output when I choose 3 -> 6. It may be a stupid question but to be honest I cannot find out where or what should I type to search to solve this problem. I am okay to see downvote but please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment
1.  What is the difference between return 1; and return 0;?
2. I tried to change, it makes me to input again and prints out the second input, not both.

Comment: I got it. But how about changing count++ to count += Load.... It makes me to input again then breaks instead of breaking after the first completed input. When I choose 3 (in order to print out info), it prints the second input, not one nor both.

Comment: Totally understand. That's why you recommended me to change return 1 to return 0. Apply if statement, it will check what the function returns to consider whether or not count will change. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `LoadEmployeeFromKey` is declared to return a *value*, and most of your `return` statements do return a value.

The problem is two-fold: First is that the function (except in one case) always return the *same* value, making it impossible to distinguish between the cases; The second problem is that you don't *check* what the function return, so it's not possible to add conditions based on that.

First of all make sure all return statements actually return a value (otherwise you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). Then return *one* value if the input was `"-1"`, and some *other* value if you fully initialized the structure. Lastly, use the returned value to check if you should increase the counter or not.

---

First of all, you must (and probably already) have a proper function prototype:

```
int LoadEmployeeFromKey(data *d);
```

Secondly, you *have* used function which returns a value before?

Lets say that the function return `1` on success, when all fields have been properly entered and initialized, and `0` otherwise, then you could use it directly in a condition:

```
if (LoadEmployeeFromKey(&employee[count]) == 1)
{
    // All data valid
    Calculation(&employee[count]);
    count++;
}
```

If the function doesn't return `1` then just don't do anything special.

Comment: I understand your recommend. But how can I declare the returned value in main()?

Comment: @HanTong Updated my answer. But if you didn't know how to do that, then you're in way over your head and should probably take a few steps back. Get a few books, read some tutorials, and kind of start over.